# Protobuf-net - list of objects with parent reference

Tags: list, reference, protobuf-net

I have a simple class with reference to parent object. All objects are in one list (even parent objects). Is it possible to keep references  references after deserialization?

In my code I have something like this:

```
    [ProtoContract]
    public class ProtoItem
    {
        [ProtoMember(1)]
        public int Value { get; set; }

        [ProtoMember(2, AsReference = true)]
        public ProtoItem BaseItem { get; set; }
    }
```

And main looks like that:

```
        static void Main()
        {
            var itemParent = new ProtoItem { Value = 1 };
            var item2 = new ProtoItem { Value = 2, BaseItem = itemParent };
            var item3 = new ProtoItem { Value = 3, BaseItem = itemParent };

            var parentListToWrite = new List<ProtoItem> {itemParent, item2, item3};

            const string file = "protofile.txt";
            try { File.Delete(file); }
            catch { };

            using (var fs = File.OpenWrite(file)) { Serializer.Serialize(fs,    
                 parentListToWrite); }

        List<ProtoItem> readList;
        using (var fs = File.OpenRead(file)) { readList = 
            Serializer.Deserialize<List<ProtoItem>>(fs); }

        if (readList[0] == readList[2].BaseItem)
        {
            //how to make it equal?
        }
        if (readList[0] == readList[1].BaseItem)
        {
            //how to make it equal?
        }
    }
```

Is it possible to deserialize that if conditions works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The protobuf specification doesn't have the notion of object identity. protobuf-net *does* (as an optionally enabled feature), but it doesn't currently work for list items directly, although I suspect it probably should. Since it would break the format, though, it would need explicit enabling if I fixed this.

But the following code works today - note that what I have done here is to wrap the top-level list items in a wrapper that just encapsulates the ProtoItem, but in doing so enables reference-tracking. Not ideal, but: it works.

```
using ProtoBuf;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

[ProtoContract(AsReferenceDefault=true)]
public class ProtoItem
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public int Value { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public ProtoItem BaseItem { get; set; }
}
[ProtoContract]
public class Wrapper
{
    [ProtoMember(1, DataFormat = DataFormat.Group)]
    public ProtoItem Item { get;set; }

    public static implicit operator ProtoItem(Wrapper value)
    {
        return value == null ? null : value.Item;
    }
    public static implicit operator Wrapper(ProtoItem value)
    {
        return value == null ? null : new Wrapper { Item = value };
    }
}



static class Program
{

    static void Main()
    {
        var itemParent = new ProtoItem { Value = 1 };
        var item2 = new ProtoItem { Value = 2, BaseItem = itemParent };
        var item3 = new ProtoItem { Value = 3, BaseItem = itemParent };

        var parentListToWrite = new List<Wrapper> { itemParent, item2, item3 };

        const string file = "protofile.txt";
        try
        { File.Delete(file); }
        catch
        { };

        using (var fs = File.OpenWrite(file))
        {
            Serializer.Serialize(fs,
    parentListToWrite);
        }

        List<Wrapper> readList;
        using (var fs = File.OpenRead(file))
        {
            readList = Serializer.Deserialize<List<Wrapper>>(fs);
        }

        if (readList[0].Item == readList[2].Item.BaseItem)
        {
            //how to make it equal?
            System.Console.WriteLine("eq");
        }
        if (readList[0].Item == readList[1].Item.BaseItem)
        {
            //how to make it equal?
            System.Console.WriteLine("eq");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are there any other collections that need hacking? I added a `AsReference = true` for the lists